# separating a string to a double array with seperators

Tags: c, arrays, string, split

i want to make a function that returns an array of doubles from a specific string.

i've tried multiple options and did not succeed

i have a given function createWeightsArray and i need to fill it.
the numofgrades will be also given which is helpful

the string will be something like: "30% 40% 50%" and i in need a double array {0.3,0.4,0.5}

this is my latest try:

```
double* createWeightsArray(char* str, int numOfGrades) {
double *gradesweight;
gradesweight = (double*)malloc(numOfGrades * sizeof(double));
int i = 0, n = 0;
while (*str != '\0') {
    while (strchr("%", *str)) ++str;
    if (*str == '\0') break;
    *(gradesweight + n) = (atof(str) / 100);
    n++;
    str = strstr(str, "% ");
    if (str == NULL) break;
    *str = '\0';
    ++str;
}
return gradesweight;
```

any help will be apprciated

Comment: Give us a string format you want to use. It should be a kind of standard format that you would pass to this function. Should we consider that you always pass "30% 40% 50%"  this kind of string?

Comment: yes! the king of string will always be like this and the number of elemts in it will be given also as numOfgrades. @Mazhar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check it out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

double* str2double(char *string, int length)
{
 int index = 0;
 const char delimitor[2] = "% "; /* Delimintor, used the break the string */
 char *token;
 double *array = malloc(sizeof(double) * length);

 if (array == NULL){
     fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate memory \n");
     return NULL;
 }

 /* get the first token */
 token = strtok(string, delimitor);

 /* walk through other tokens */
 for( index=0; token != NULL && index < length ; index++)
 {
     array[index] = strtod(token, &token) / 100;
     token = strtok(NULL, delimitor);
 }
 return array;   
}

int main()
{
   char str[] = "30% 40% 80% 60%";
   double *ptr = str2double(str, 4); 

   if (ptr != NULL) {
   for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf( "%f\n", ptr[i]);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped @Beginner

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok`like this

```
double* createWeightsArray(char* str1, int numOfGrades) {
double *gradesweight;
char *str =strdup(str1);
gradesweight = (double*)malloc(numOfGrades * sizeof(double));
int i = 0;

*gradesweight = atof(strtok(str,"%"))/100;
i++;
while (--numOfGrades) {
    *(gradesweight+i) = atof(strtok(NULL,"%") )/100;
    i++;
}
return gradesweight;
}
```

As you are certain that numOfGrades are provided so better check for zero value of numberOfGrades before calling this function.

Comment: this is a goo solution tho i get the same error i got before. theres a writing violation in the atof line. and i cant understand why

Comment: Are you passing the string to this function like("60%20%40",3) ?? then it will show an error. Because strtok() alter the string you passed. So you can't pass a constant string to it. If you are going to use this approach you should first store the string in character array like this char[] ="60%20%40" then pass it to your function

Comment: or you can duplicate the string in your function and perform the operations on that string. –Edited the code with strdup

Comment: i didnt know that! thaks so much!